# How do I redim/preserve my array to prevent run time error 9

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an API to grab data from a Wix website (not shown), it then replaces values in the string, before splitting the string into columns via text to column function. It then stores the range in an array, I have added `laArray` to the watch window and I can see every instance of laArray(1 to 56) but the issue is I have a `run time error 9, Subscript out of range` when trying to loop through the array in order to have each array value as a vertical list instead of a horizontal one.

I did initially try to use string manipulation instead of text to columns and replace but needed a quick fix so ended up doing it this way.

```
JSON = Cells(1, 1)
lcReplace = Array("}", "{", "/", "\", """", ":", ";", "items", "[", "]", "_")

For Each A In lcReplace
  JSON = Replace(JSON, A, " ")
Next A

Cells(2, 1) = JSON
Cells(2, 1).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A4"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False

g = Cells(4, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

Dim laArray As Variant
laArray = (Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, g)).Value2)
laArray = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, g)))

For f = LBound(laArray) To UBound(laArray)
   Cells(f + 4, 3) = laArray(f)
Next f
```

**Summary:**

Run time error 9 when trying to make a cell equal to my array, from what I have read I need to Redim preserve the array, I tried that before and in the f loop but it still returns a run time error, How can I prevent this? Is there an alternative to dimensioning as from what I have read it will make the code rather slow when dimensioning multiple times.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Example]

Comment: This may not be applicable but if you are trying to work with JSON in VBA, you might want to take a look at this https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: I did have a read about that before I posted as that was one of my 3 options, 1) VBA JSON library, 2) API for conversion, 3)  transformation macro in excel. 
If I cant get the above to work then I will just do a horrible copy and paste job or loop through each value without an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`laArray` is a *2-dimensional* array, as can be confirmed using the Watch window.

For example, if `g` is 10, then `laArray` will have a size of `1 to 10, 1 to 1`.

You need to specify the second dimension with your current approach.

`Cells(f + 4, 3) = laArray(f, 1)`

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot Toddleson. In all honestly I have done a 'for each cell in array do something loop' but it's great to the know the above for next time.

Comment: The solution is correct, but the explanation isn't. `laArray` is a 2D `Variant` array that contains `Variant/String` *values*. The error is thrown because the array is two-dimensional and the 2nd dimension index isn't supplied in the OP's code. Solution is either to re-transpose the array into a one-dimensional array, or to supply an index for the 2nd dimension of the array, as `laArray(f, 1)` does.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also still quite new to VBA and programming. I just explained it the way I understood it, but I appreciate the corrections. It's always nice to learn from those with experience.